# How to couple this floating sensor to this amplifier properly?

Tags: amplifier, signal

There is a sensor with two terminals similar to below:

I cannot provide more info on the sensor because I don't have. All I know is it is produces 0 to 150mV voltage when squeezed. And picks up so much 50Hz CM interference.

I will use [this](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8221.html?doc=UG-261.pdf#product-overview) InAmp for CM rejection and gain and a dual supply. But Im confused how should the sensor be coupled to the amplifier. The sensor has two output terminals. But the InAmp has three inputs +Vin, -Vin and Ref.

What Figure below should I use to wire these sensor(Vin in the diagram) to the InAmp?

to be updated

(R1, R2, R3 just sets the gain)

Comment: Don't delete images once answers have been posted! If you need to modify your question just add it at the end.

Comment: I will edit these days its nit finished yet. There were something wrong

Answer (score 2):

Figure 3 will center the transducer around ground, which is probably what you want if using pos and neg rails.

Figure 2 will make the transducer voltage from 0V to ground, but then you are missing half of your dynamic range of the amp. If you do run this scheme you may want to center the output around a different ref value than ground if piping the value to an ADC.

Figure 1 is floating, you need to have a 1MegΩ to ground or something on the inputs to give it a DC offset, otherwise both pins will float and it could go out of range.

Comment: There is evaluation board specifically made for this amplifier here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/UG-261.pdf Please see the third page. It recommends R3 and R5 for AC coupling only. Back to my question if I go for Figure 3 in my question, should the R4 and R5 be equal and matched?

Comment: It depends on the offset your application will tolerate, the better the matching the lower the DC offset. I would think 1% would be good enough for a gain of 100, you may want to provide extra resistor spots on the PCB if you need to stick in another resistor in parallel to pull the dc offset up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to consider

**Ground referencing**

If neither input of the transducer sees ground (by either grounding or though a resistor) the input pins could go outside the supply voltages, meaning that you rail your instrumentation amplifier. Figure 1 has this problem and should be crossed off the list of consideration. Figures 2 and 3 do not have this problem.

**Frequency range considerations**

A transducer has infinite impedance at DC, and anytime you put a resistor across it's input you've formed a high pass filter. This resistor could be two resistors you added in Figure 3, or the input impedance of the AD8221 in Figure 2. For example, if your transducer is 10 nF, the two series resistors in Figure 3 give you a corner frequency of 796 Hz \$\left( = \frac{1 } { 2 \times \pi \times \text{10 nF} \times \text{20 kOhm} } \right)  \$.

Adding some resistance across the transducer can get rid of low frequency garbage signals: mains noise, noise due to random vibrations, and noise due to the pyro-electric effect (charge with respect to a changing temperature). For example transducers we have in the office pick up people walking across the room or a trucks driving by. If you hook up the transducer like shown in Figure 2, you'll see a change in the output of the amplifier whenever you wave your hand over the transducer due to a small change in temperature.

Putting too large a value of resistor across the transducer will increase your noise issue due to Johnson noise:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

**Maximizing the output voltage**

If the goal is to maximize the output voltage of the amplifier, according to figures 8 and 9 of the AD8221 datasheet, you get the largest output voltage when the common mode voltage is zero.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8221.pdf

Figure 3 seems like the winner in this respect, but a little voice in the back of my mind keeps asking is this always true? What happens if the force applied to the transducer is unipolar (always in compression for example)? Would it make more sense to go with Figure 2, but add a resistor for filtering in parallel with the transducer? That voice is smarter than me most times.

**Reference pin**

The reference voltage pin is used to apply a DC offset to your output signal. You can use it to trim the output (remove offset errors) or turn a bi-polar output into a uni-polar one to interface with electronics that have a single supply.